# HTML div height auto

Tags: html

I have an requirement where inside an TR, i will have three TDs . First TD and Third TD should be scrollable and second TD is an ruler Image such as dividing first and third (similar to using frames)

Without setting height in first TD the scroll is not working and also affecting the height of third TD. How to make the height auto. Height should be that of window's height (I will maximise and minimize the window). Have pasted the code-snippet below

In the below mode, i have mentioned specifically the height, I dont want to do that way. I want it to get set automatically but with same result

```
<td width="55%">                            
    <div style="height:350px;overflow:auto">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%=passageText%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <img src="/Images/reads/rulerVertical.gif" width="3" height="400"  border="0"/>
</td>
<td>
    HERE I WILL PLACE THE STUFFS OF THIRD TD
</td>
```

Comment: Why do you layout with a table element and not with floating divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a floating div it should be far more easy:

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
  height:100%
}
#div1 {
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  overflow:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background:#6666CC;  
}
#div2 {
  height:100%;
  width:45%;
  overflow:auto;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#6666CC;
  margin-left:5%;
}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1">
</div>

<div id="div2">
</div>

</body>
```