# Floating DIV scrollbar issue. Remove window scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html

Further to this suggestion [HTML div height auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701021/html-div-height-auto) I used Floating DIV in my project to replicate FRAME-LIKE-UI

In existing product, they have used frames for UI. For which in new version, I used floating-divs

But the requirement is to make the UI look alike existing one.

So, in existing product, the scroll bar appears only for the frames and not for the whole window

Whereas in my solution, the frame appears both in the div as well as in the window. I have attached the screen-shot of both "expected" and "reality" scenarios. Please have a look at that too

[image]

The css i use is

```
#div1, #div2 {
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    height: 550px;
}

#div1{
    width: 50%;
    border-right : 2px solid grey;
}

#div2 {
    width: 48%;
}
```

I dont need the scroll bar which the browser gives rather I need it to be exactly like how FRAMES behaves.

Thanks.
Arun

Comment: Am not able to attach the screen-shots :-(. trying to do it again and again though

Comment: Just to point out without being picky, it's good practice anywhere to give meaningful names to your variables/objects. Try using leftDiv instead of div1.

Comment: Also, I would see trouble if the user makes the window smaller than the divs and thus can't scroll down to see the actual floating divs you meantion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding the browser scrollbar with

`body { overflow-y: hidden; }`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a height of 550px for the floating div elements. Make sure your body + header is not greater than the visible real estate of your screen, this will help you avoid scrollbars. Otherwise you can always use `overflow : hidden` for your body and the div elements to avoid the scrollbars altogther (this approach is not recommended).

Also, have a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/).